# Как создать скрытую папку

Tags: windows

я хочу сделать папку которая не будет видна при включенном отображении. Я видел подобные папки в системных каталогах виндовс. Подскажите как сделать подобное

Comment: правый клик на папке --> Атрибуты "Скрытый"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы папку не было видно даже при включении отображения (я так понимаю вы имеете ввиду отображение скрытых файлов и папок), вам необходимо будет добавить / поменять атрибуты этой папки, такие как +s и +h

Пример:
attrib +s +h "Название вашей папки"

Таким образом папка будет считаться системной и скрытой

Comment: Вот более подробный пример создания и добавление атрибута папки:

mkdir "название вашей папки" && attrib +s +h "название вашей папки"